# How to make my javascript function async when it's scoped

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, javascript-scope

I have a method called 'updateStatus' in one of my js files. I'm scoping everything in each JS file like below.

Now I want to make this function asynchronous, but if I put a async in front of the function declaration like below I get an error saying it expects a semi colon on that same line.

```
scope.updateStatus = async function(profileId, isConnected)
```

```js
'use strict';

// Set local tp namespace
if (typeof yb === 'undefined')
  var yb = {};

$(function() {
  yb.chat.initializeChat();
});

yb.chat = new function() {
  var scope = this;

  scope.initializeChat = function() {
    scope.initializeHub();
  };

  scope.updateStatus = function(profileId, isConnected) {
    // do some work
  };

  scope.initializeHub = function() {
    scope.chat = $.connection.chatHub;

    scope.chat.client.setConnectionStatus = function(profileId, isConnected) {
      scope.updateStatus(profileId, isConnected);
    };
  };

};
```

Comment: Are you using await in that function or are you only using promises?

Comment: What do you mean by "scoping", the assignment to a property?

Comment: That code should work. Are you sure you are running it in an ES8 compatible environment?

Comment: no, I'm not using await.

Comment: I'll edit my example to provide the full js file

Comment: I just tested in Chrome and it's working, but not IE. Anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

**tldr**: Overall, the answer to your question is to do one of the following three things:

1. Use browsers that support async
2. Use Promises and use browsers that support Promises
3. Do not use async (or Promises).

It would help to explain where you get that error. I'm assuming it's when executing the code in your browser. Further, I'm assuming your browser simply does not support the `async` keyword.

Have a look at the following code:

```
const scope = {};

scope.foobar = async function() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('foobar');
    resolve();
  });
};

scope.foobar();
```

If you execute this code (e.g. via https://jsbin.com) in a recent Firefox or Chrome browser, it works. However, in an other/older browser it might cause the error you are describing.

If my assumption is wrong, please further clarify.

Comment: I just tested it in Chrome and it works, but not in IE

Comment: I´m replying here as I cannot reply to your comment on your question. No, there is nothing you can do to fix this. The browser simply does not support it. An alternative to async is to use Promises (if supported by the browser). See here for the support of async: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-async_functions

Comment: Overall, the answer to your question is to do one of the following three things:

1. Use browsers that support async
2. Use Promises and use browsers that support Promises
3. Do not use async (or Promises)